# make a div block share a line?

Tags: html, css

-edit- example: http://jsfiddle.net/AXCap/

Html

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><nobr>
            <a href="/a" class="one">a</a>
            <a href="/b" class="two">b</a>
            <a href="/c" class="three">c</a>
            </nobr></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Css

```
li a
{
    display: inline;
    background:red;
}
li a.two
{
    background:teal;
}

li a.three
{
    display: block;
    background:green;
}
```

I want the three links to be on the same line but the 3rd must be a block to take up remaining space in the li so that it is clickable. I tried a number of things and the example above is my closest result. How do i make the 3rd link share the same line and a block so the resut of the line is clickable?

I tried float left and that does not allow the third link to take up remaining space.

Comment: Can you post the CSS that goes with those class names?

Comment: it doesnt exist. I deleted them and its just .one {} .two {} .three {} ATM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that http://jsfiddle.net/3L7MW/ ?

```
li 
{
    width:100%;
}
li a.one
{
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
li a.two
{
    float:left;
    background:pink;
}

li a.three
{
    display:block;
    background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post the CSS with the class names associated with the links.

If they are not doing any positioning, then this might work:

```
<li><nobr><a href=... class="one"><a href=... class="two"><a href=... class="three"></nobr></li>
```

HTH

Comment: Interesting tag. I never seen it before. I had no luck with that. (see various links i left in question and comments)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving one and two a `display: inline` and then give 3 a `display: block`

If that doesn't work, give one and two a `float: left` and 3 a `clear: left`

**EDIT**

Scratch that. I misread your original post.

What about giving all 3 a `display: inline`?

Comment: then it doesnt take the remaining space http://jsfiddle.net/gF3Dw/. Heres the other try http://jsfiddle.net/nyRmH/

Comment: Can you give each one of them a set width? Like give the first 2 a width of 30% and the last one a width of 70%?